Dynamics API Second Argument Error on NextJS15 while Deploying on Vercel
Type error: Route "src/app/api/student/[studentId]/route.ts" has an invalid "GET" export:
Type "{ params: { studentId: string; }; }" is not a valid type for the function's second argument.
export async function GET(
  req: NextRequest,
  context: { params: { studentId: string } }
) {
  const { studentId } = context.params;

  try {
    const student = await prisma.students.findUnique({
      where: { id: parseInt(studentId, 10) },
    });

    if (!student) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Student not found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    const formattedStudent = {
      ...student,
      birthDate: student.birthDate ? formatDate(student.birthDate) : null,
      accommodationStart: student.accommodationStart
        ? formatDate(student.accommodationStart)
        : null,
      courseStart: student.courseStart ? formatDate(student.courseStart) : null,
      accommodationEnd: student.accommodationEnd
        ? formatDate(student.accommodationEnd)
        : null,
      courseEnd: student.courseEnd ? formatDate(student.courseEnd) : null,
      arrivalDate: student.arrivalDate ? formatDate(student.arrivalDate) : null,
      departureDate: student.departureDate
        ? formatDate(student.departureDate)
        : null,
    };

    return NextResponse.json(formattedStudent, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    console.error(
      "Error fetching student:",
      error instanceof Error ? error.message : error
    );
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: "Failed to fetch student",
        details:
          error instanceof Error ? error.message : "An unknown error occurred",
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}


please help me fix it

this seemed to fix it for me:
wrap params in Promise as shown in the code below.
context: { params: { month: string } }
to
{ params } : { params: Promise<{ month: string }> }
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional

The error arises because the second argument (context) of the GET handler in the Next.js API route must conform to a specific type expected by the framework. Next.js expects context to be typed as NextApiRequest for standard API routes or a specific type when used in app directories.
In the /api routes under the Next.js app directory, the context argument's type should match the framework's expectations. Specifically, in dynamic API routes like [studentId], the params field needs proper typing.
To resolve,

Import RouteHandlerContext :

import { RouteHandlerContext } from 'next';


Replace the context parameter type with:

context: RouteHandlerContext<{ params: { studentId: string } }>

